# create than import a class that can save the passed input data in memory to reuse

Tags: python, oop

I created a class called `OnlineClusturing` that I want to import in a new `.py` file where some `xt` data will be passed as input during the execution of the whole script:

```py
import OnelineClustering
from DataGenerator import generator

for xt in generator:
  result = OnlineClustering.PredictNextValue(xt)
```

Inside the `OnlineClustering` Class I need to save the `xt` data to reuse it in the next time where `OnlineClusturing.PredictNextValue(xt)` is called.

One solution could be to create a list to store the xt in each iteration and pass this list to the `PredictNextValue()` thsi way:

```py
import OnelineClustering
from DataGenerator import generator

list_ = []
for xt in generator:
   result = OnlineClustering.PredictNextValue(xt,list_)
   list_.append(xt)
```

But I want a solution that allow to store this data inside the `OnlineClustering` class

Comment: OnlineClustering appears to be a module, not a class.

Comment: Just put the list inside the `OnlineClustering` **module** and have `PredictNextValue()` append each value it's going to return to that list (or add a new function to the module to do this if it's called).